# Removing rows in data frame using row numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following doubt:

```
 cc <- c(1,3,4,6)  # some vector with positive integers, max(cc)<=nrow(df)
 df1 <- df[cc,]
 df2 <- df[-cc,]
 n <- nrow(df1)+nrow(df2)
```

When data frame df has a huge number of rows, say around 10M and `length(cc)` is around 1M, then why `n` is not equal to `nrow(df)`?

I cannot think of any reason for that..

Comment: Do you have any duplicates in `cc` in the original dataset?  Try `cc <- unique(cc)`

Comment: yup  there are .. thank you..

Comment: You could post that as an answer and close this.

Comment: You can elaborate the answer a bit more with `cc <- unique(cc)` It may help somebody in the future.  I meant (sorry a typo) you can either answer or close it by deleting the post.

Comment: sure...................

Answer (score 0):

The reason was duplicates in the vector `cc`. `cc=unique(cc)` would give us `nrow(df1)+nrow(df2)=n`.